# Do I have to detect Changes for global service provider in angular?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using firebase with angular to create a web app that needs authentication.

According to my knowledge,that the firebase, after a successful authentication sends specific and limited attributes to the client (displayName, PhotoURL, email uid, ...) . What if I want to add other data? How can I do that?

example:

I want to send the user phoneNumber and his job title every time the user has successfully authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom token for firebase authentication. Firebase uses JWT(JSON Web Tokens). But you will need back end to create such token on first call and then authenticate with the use of this token with firebase.
Instructions how to create firebase custom token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

And if you want to use angularfire to login:

```
import { AuthMethods, AuthProviders, AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2';

constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

customSignIn() {
  this.auth.login({
    method: AuthMethods.CustomToken,
    provider: AuthProviders.Custom
  });
}
```